# Usefulness of the "Lagrange function" $\Lambda(\mathbf x,\mathbf \lambda) = f(\mathbf x) - \sum_{i=1}^m \mathbf \lambda_i \Phi_i(\mathbf x)$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, intuition, lagrange-multiplier

Suppose that our surface $M\subset \Bbb R^n$ (or manifold) is defined to be the level set of a sufficiently nice function $\Phi:\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R^m$ ($m<n$), i.e. $M = \{\mathbf x\in\Bbb R^n: \Phi(\mathbf x) =\mathbf 0 \}$. Let $f:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$ be a $C^1$ function, we wish to solve the problem
$$\begin{align} 
\text{minimize}\quad &f(\mathbf x) \\
\text{subject to}\quad &\mathbf x\in M.
\end{align}$$
It is well-known that if $\mathbf x^*\in M$ is a solution to the above problem, then there exists a vector $\mathbf \lambda^*\in\Bbb R^m$ (or a real number if $m=1$) such that
$$\tag{*}\label{a}
\nabla_{\mathbf x} f(\mathbf x^*) = \sum_{i=1}^m \lambda^*_i \nabla_{\mathbf x}\Phi_i(\mathbf x^*).
$$
This is called *the method of Lagrange multipliers*.

It is also very popular to rewrite the above using the auxiliary function called the **Lagrange function** $\Lambda:\Bbb R^{n+m}\to \Bbb R$ defined as
$$
\Lambda(\mathbf x,\mathbf \lambda) = f(\mathbf x) - \sum_{i=1}^m \mathbf \lambda_i \Phi_i(\mathbf x),
$$
so that \eqref{a} and the constraint $\mathbf x^*\in M$ can be recasted as
$$
\nabla_{(\mathbf x,\mathbf \lambda)} \Lambda(\mathbf x^*,\mathbf \lambda^*) = \mathbf 0,  
$$
or written separately as
$$
\partial_{ x_j} \Lambda(\mathbf x^*,\mathbf \lambda^*) = 0, \quad  
\partial_{\lambda_i} \Lambda(\mathbf x^*,\mathbf \lambda^*) = 0 \quad\text{for all $j=1,\dots,n$ and $i=1,\dots,m$}.
$$

---

I have always found the formulation $\nabla_{(\mathbf x,\mathbf \lambda)} \Lambda(\mathbf x^*,\mathbf \lambda^*) = \mathbf 0$ to be a bit unenlightening. To me it is nothing but a shorthand of writing \eqref{a} and the fact that $\mathbf x^*\in M$ together in a single line, and at times even obscures the important geometric meaning that \eqref{a} conveys (from my experience of being a TA on this subject). Hence my questions today:

-Is there anything inherently interesting about the function $\Lambda(\mathbf x,\mathbf \lambda)$ itself (beside the fact that it's an auxiliary function for the Lagrange multiplier method)?

-Is there any geometric (or otherwise) intuition that is naturally associated with $\Lambda(\mathbf x,\mathbf \lambda)$?

-Is there a better answer I can give to my students when they ask "What does $\Lambda(\mathbf x,\mathbf \lambda)$ represent?" except "It's just a shorthand for writing \eqref{a}."?

I'm hopeful that there's probably some good ways of interpreting  $\Lambda(\mathbf x,\mathbf \lambda)$ that I'm not aware of yet. Personally, I've been trying to avoid using it altogether if I can because I'm not sure what to make of it. Today might be a good day to fix that.

Comment: I don't know how useful this would be, but $\Lambda$ is a function that takes on the same values as $f$ on the desired set, but the extra "penalty" alters the gradient so it points in the correct direction for the new extrema, like a wobbly pudding that keeps the same outline on a plate but different slopes at the edges. This is the same intuition behind the solution to the inhomogeneous Dirichlet problem in PDEs where $f$ plays the role of the inhomogeneous term.

Comment: In the sentence _It is well-known that there exists a vector $\lambda^* \in \mathbb{R}^m$ such that if $x^* \in M$ is a solution to the above problem_ the order of quantifiers should be reversed.

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz Thanks for spotting the mistake, I was a bit careless there.

Comment: @NinadMunshi That's a nice viewpoint I'd say. Would you mind expanding the comment into an answer? Maybe elaborating a bit on the similarity to the inhomogeneous Dirichlet problem (perhaps with a small example). Since it seems there's no other satisfactory answer (at least for now) I'm considering accepting yours.